# Iterator for both lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.x

I have a parameter dictionary holding complex data composed of strings, lists and other dictionaries. Now I want to iterate through this data.

My problem is the way - the best practice - for having an iterator, which iterates both lists and dictionaries.

What I have:

```
def parse_data(key, value):
    iterator = None

    if isinstance(value, dict):
        iterator = value.items()
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        iterator = enumerate(value)

    if iterator is not None:
        for key, item in iterator:
            parse_data(key, item)
        return

    # do some cool stuff with the rest
```

This does not look very pythonish. I thought of a function similar to [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) giving me the possibilty to iterate over both key and item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this i quite pythonic. I would just change it to:

```
def parse_data:

    if isinstance(value, dict):
        iterator = value.items()
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        iterator = enumerate(value)
    else:
        return

    for key, item in iterator:
        parse_data(value, key, item)

    # do some cool stuff with the rest
```

Comment: With this, `# do some cool stuff with the rest` is never called.

Comment: What? Of course it is. The only premature `return` only kicks in if `value` is of an inappropriate type.

Comment: My idea with this comment in my code was to sign the place where I deal with other types of values such as strings. That's the reason why I used `iterator = None` for initializing not to have too complex conditional structures. But your right with it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if there is a shorter way of doing it, but Python is built to do one thing many different ways. Maybe this could be another way of doing it. I haven't tested it so it might not work.

```
def parse_data(key,value):
    iterator = isinstance(value,dict) 

    if iterator is False and isinstance(value,list):
        iterator = enumerate(value)

    if iterator is not None: 
        for key,item in iterator: 
            parse_data(key,item) 
        return      

    #do some cool stuff with the rest
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `dict.get`? I only can call `get` on an instance of a dictionary. It's not a static method.

Comment: Right, right! I will change the code to reflect the `isistance` command.

Comment: "Python is built to do one thing many different ways" The Python Zen disagrees with you.

Comment: But thats one more reason to ask this question - to see other possibilities and solutions. Or do I misled your statement?